# How to pass arguments to SPE's Invoke-RemoteScript

Tags: powershell-extensions

I want to pass some arguments to a script block that will be run on a remote Sitecore instance via SPE remoting.  I wrote this script as a test, but it's not working.

```ps
$session = New-ScriptSession -ConnectionUri "http://sc81up3" -Username admin -Password b
Invoke-RemoteScript -Session $session -ScriptBlock { param($name) Write-Output "hi $name" } -Arguments @{"name"="Ben"}
Stop-ScriptSession -Session $session
```

This wasn't my first attempt.  I tried, just passing `"Ben"` as the `Argument` parameter, but that caused an error about not being able to convert a string to a hashtable.  When I pass the hashtable as shown above, I don't get an error, but the output is just `hi`, so it seems the value isn't getting passed.

What is the correct way to pass arguments to the script block executed by Invoke-RemoteScript?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The SPE [Gitbook](https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/remoting) provides some alternate examples using the `$using:VARIABLE` syntax.

**Example:** The following will pass the `$data` object into the scriptblock for remote execution.

```powershell
Import-Module -Name SPE
$session = New-ScriptSession -Username michael -Password b -ConnectionUri https://spe.dev.local

$data = @{"name"="Michael"}
Invoke-RemoteScript -Session $session -ScriptBlock {
    Write-Output "Hi $(($using:data).name)"
}
Stop-ScriptSession -Session $session
```

**Note:** The current version of the remoting module requires you to wrap the `$using:data` in parenthesis if you want to directly access properties. Otherwise assign it to a variable first.

Comment: Ah, I quickly scanned through that looking for examples with the `-Arguments` parameter.  I guess I was looking for the wrong thing.  Is `$using` preferred over `-Arguments`?

Comment: I prefer because it looks cleaner and requires less typing. Either are acceptable.

Comment: If I try to pass an array with the $using syntax, only the first item makes it through.  Do I need to do something special for arrays?

Comment: Interesting observation. I'll investigate.

Comment: For reference, this should be fixed in 4.2 or newer.

Answer (score 5):

I found an example in the comments included in the `Invoke-RemoteScript.ps1` script file.  Here is a modified version of my script that outputs `hi Ben` as expected:

```ps
$session = New-ScriptSession -ConnectionUri "http://sc81up3" -Username admin -Password b
Invoke-RemoteScript -Session $session -ScriptBlock { Write-Output "hi $($params.name)" } -Arguments @{"name"="Ben"}
Stop-ScriptSession -Session $session
```

The hashtable that you pass with `-Arguments` is accessible within the script as the properties on the `$params` variable.