# Pass Variables to SPE Script from PowerShell via Remoting

Tags: powershell-extensions

I'm having trouble passing variables from a PowerShell script into a SPE Script.  I'm attempting to call the SPE script from a PowerShell file on the file system.  I'm trying to pass in variables that can be used by the script, but they appear to always be empty from the viewpoint of the script.  When I try to call the script directly from within ISE in Sitecore, the values are accessible.

Here's what I'm trying:

### The PowerShell Script:

I'm referencing a script via GUID and passing in a varaible named "name."

```
$scriptArguments = @{
    "name" = "CRAAIG"
}

Write-Host "scriptArguments: $($scriptArguments.name)"

$session = New-ScriptSession -Username admin -Password b -ConnectionUri http://sc920.local
$jobId = Invoke-RemoteScript -Session $session -ScriptBlock { Get-Item -Path "master:" -ID "{790F6017-B495-4C8C-B9CF-6119669E1688}" | Invoke-Script -ArgumentList $scriptArguments } -AsJob

Wait-RemoteScriptSession -Session $session -Id $jobId -Delay 5 -Verbose
Stop-ScriptSession -Session $session
```

### The SPE Script

I've obviously boiled it down here, but all I'd like to do is access the variables passed in.  I'm attempting to writing the values to the SPE log.

```
param($params)
 
Write-Log "params: $($params)"
Write-Log "params.name: $($params.name)"
Write-Log "args: $($args)"
Write-Log "args.name $($args.name)"
```

### The Results in the Log File

All of these values end up null.

```
ManagedPoolThread #15 09:46:04 INFO  params: 
ManagedPoolThread #15 09:46:04 INFO  params.name: 
ManagedPoolThread #15 09:46:04 INFO  args: 
ManagedPoolThread #15 09:46:04 INFO  args.name
```

As mentioned, I have attempted to call the script itself from within ISE and when take `Invoke-RemoteScript` out of it and call:

```
$scriptArguments = @{
    "name" = "CRAAIG"
}

Get-Item -Path "master:" -ID "{790F6017-B495-4C8C-B9CF-6119669E1688}" | Invoke-Script -ArgumentList $scriptArguments
```

The variables can be received in the `$args` variable as a hashtable in this manner.

This appears to be following what Michael and Ben have said in a couple of places ([How to pass arguments to SPE's Invoke-RemoteScript](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/1980/how-to-pass-arguments-to-spes-invoke-remotescript) and [Sitecore PowerShell Extensions Remoting variables not working in Octopus Deploy](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/10757/sitecore-powershell-extensions-remoting-variables-not-working-in-octopus-deploy)), but I can't make it work.

PS - Last thought that just occurred to me: Does HTTPS have anything to do with it?  I'm just using HTTP locally and thought that the config supported this.  Relevant section from showconfig:

```
<remoting requireSecureConnection="false" enabled="true">
<authorization>
<add Permission="Allow" IdentityType="User" Identity="sitecore\admin" patch:source="Cognifide.PowerShell.Patch.config"/>
</authorization>
</remoting>
```

Am I missing something fundamental here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I solved this.  It came down to formatting and combining a few concepts.  I needed to use `$using` in order to get the variable across.

Here is the revised `$jobId` line that I used to make this work:

```
$jobId = Invoke-RemoteScript -Session $session -ScriptBlock { Get-Item -Path "master:" -ID "{790F6017-B495-4C8C-B9CF-6119669E1688}" | Invoke-Script -ArgumentList $($using:scriptArguments)} -AsJob
```